# Pandas DataFrame pivot_table Year and Month in rows, items as Columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have the following sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "item", "qty"], data=[['2022-10-11','apple',2],['2022-10-12','orange',4],['2021-11-01','apple',5],['2021-11-02','orange',8],['2021-12-01','apple',9],['2021-12-02','orange',3],['2022-01-01','banana',2],['2022-01-02','apple',1],['2022-01-03','orange',6],['2022-02-02','apple',7],['2022-02-03','orange',4]])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

which looks like this

[image]

I would like to group rows into Years and Months, and items into columns, with row and column subtotals. Using an Excel pivot table, it would be done as so:

[image]

### **pd.pivot_table approach**

Now, using

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='qty', index='date', columns='item', aggfunc='sum', fill_value='', margins=True)
```

I get something close but without the Year and Month row grouping:
[image]

If I replace `index='date'` by `index=[pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')]` I get an error:

```
KeyError: "[TimeGrouper(key='date', freq=<MonthEnd>, axis=0, sort=True, closed='right', label='right', how='mean', convention='e', origin='start_day')] not in index"
```

If I keep `index=[pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')]` but remove the `margins=True`, I get the pivot table but without the subtotals:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='qty', index=[pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')], columns='item', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0) #removed margins=True
```

[image]

How can I have both the Year and Month groupings, and the subtotals?

### **groupby approach**

As an alternative, I tried using groupby as follows. However the items show up as rows instead of columns, and I'm not sure how to get row (and column) subtotals.

```
df.groupby([df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month, 'item']).agg({'qty':'sum'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for helper columns `year` and `month` and pass to `pivot_table`:

```
(df.assign(year = df.date.dt.year,month = df.date.dt.month)
   .pivot_table(values='qty', 
                index=['year','month'], 
                columns='item', 
                aggfunc='sum', 
                fill_value='', 
                margins=True))
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Bonus question(s): how to then sort by either row or the column subtotal?

Comment: Do you think `df.sort_values('All', axis=1)` ?

Comment: With that I get the error `ValueError: The index label 'All' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.`

Comment: @fortuneRice - then use `df = df.sort_values(('All',''), axis=1)`